# How to convert a String to an Enum in Dart?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I get a snapshot from Firestore like this:

```
return userCollection
    .doc(uid)
    .collection('values')
    .where(
      "created",
      isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: fromDate,
      isLessThan: toDate,
    )
    .orderBy('created', descending: true)
    .snapshots()
    .map((list) =>
        list.docs.map((doc) => Values.fromSnapshot(doc)).toList());
```

then I convert it to a Values Model:

```
  Values.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot)
      : created = snapshot.data()!['created'],
        type = snapshot.data()!['type'],
        value = snapshot.data()!['value'].toDouble();
```

The "type" is a String. How can I convert it to a specific `ValuesType` Enum?

```
enum ValueType { first, second, third }
```

The String has not the same name: For example "one", "two", "three".
How is the right way to do this?

Comment: You are not giving enough information. What even is `ValueType`?  The `toValueType()` you tried simply returns a `Map` because that's what it literally says. What do you exactly expect? Please explain it better

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I dont want to have a Model, I want to convert the string to a enum. I edited the text above. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your enum to this for example

```
enum ValueType {
  first,
  second,
  third;

  static ValueType fromString(String s) => switch (s) {
        "one" => first,
        "two" => second,
        "three" => third,
        _ => first
      };
}
```

And then use it as

```
    type = ValueType.fromString(snapshot.data()!['type']),
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd go for the following method:

```
enum Foo {
  bar,
  baz,
}

final myEnumString = 'bar';
final myEnumValue = Foo.values.byName(myEnumString);
```

This won't require any extra methods to be written or updated as enums change.

In your case this would be:

```
final type = ValueType.values.byName(snapshot.data()!['type']);
```

Comment: Very slick, I love code that solves problems without a maintenance overhead.

Comment: thanks, but this is not working if the enum is different to the firestore string.

Comment: Ah, okay. Sorry I missed the (obviously crucial) part about it not being the same name stored :) Then Ivo's solution is best.

Answer (score 0):

I like @robert-sandberg 's answer using `ValueType.values.byName()` but unfortunately this throws if the value is not found (see [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/EnumByName/byName.html)).  This may be OK if there's an erroneous value in your Firestore but if the value is optional (could be `null`, or absent from the database) then this creates a lot of `try` / `catch` overhead.

An alternative is to define a custom version of the `.byName` function (which is defined in the `EnumByName` [extension](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/EnumByName.html)) so that it returns `null` (instead of throwing) if a string value is not matched to the enum name. The following is a simple modification of the `byName` extension [source code](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/EnumByName/byName.html) from the `dart:core` library. Simply add it to your application code:

```dart
extension EnumByNameOrNull<T extends Enum> on Iterable<T> {
  /// Finds the enum value in this list with name [name].
  ///
  /// Modified from [byName] in [EnumByName] from enum.dart in dart:core
  /// Goes through this collection looking for an enum with
  /// name [name], as reported by [EnumName.name].
  /// Returns the first value with the given name, or null if not found
  T? byNameOrNull(String name) {
    for (var value in this) {
      if (value.name == name) return value;
    }
    // Used to throw ArgumentError now returns null
    return null;
  }
}
```

You can now use this as:

```dart
final ValueType? type = ValueType.values.byNameOrNull(snapshot.data()!['type']);
```

Note that this returns an optional enum of type `ValueType`.

Another option is to combine this and build on @ivo 's answer. I love the simplicity of use of this approach, but don't like that this requires entering and maintaining `String` equivalent text for each enum value.  However we can make this generic by matching to the enum `.name` string, similar to the extension above.  Thus modifying @ivo's solution we get:

```dart
enum ValueType {
  first,
  second,
  third;

  static ValueType? fromName(String name) {
    for (var value in ValueType.values) {
      if (value.name == name) return value;
    }
    return null;
  }}
```

Again this is implemented to return `null` if the `name` parameter string is not found, but it could be easily modified to return a default enum value.
To use this becomes very simply:

```dart
final ValueType? type = ValueType.fromName(snapshot.data()!['type']);
```

Note I've renamed the function to `.fromName` as this matches the enum `.name`

```
assert(ValueType.first.name == 'first');
assert(ValueType.first == ValueType.fromName('first'));
```

This is in contrast to:

```dart
assert(ValueType.first.toString() == 'ValueType.first');
```

If preferred, it would be easy to modify or add a function in your enum called `.fromString` that matches to the enum `.toString()` instead to `.name`.

Answer (score -1):

I'd go for the following method:

```
enum ValueType { first, second, third }

Values.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>snapshot):created =
snapshot.data()!['created'],
 type = ValueType.values.byName(snapshot.data()!['type']),
 value = snapshot.data()!['value'].toDouble();
enter code here
```