# Dart Enum extension to generate an enum from a string

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

When accessing enum values from a database, such as Firestore, they are often stored as strings and need to be converted to the corresponding enum value.  There are several ways of doing this, as for example covered in this StackOverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77022977/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-dart) and elaborated in my own answer there.

What I'd like to do however is to be able to combine the 2 approaches covered there to create an `extension` on `Enum` such that it becomes super simple and intuitive to covert a string to an enum, as in the following example:

```dart
enum Fruit { apple, orange, banana }

final myFruit = Fruit.fromName('apple');  // Desired functionality
assert(myFruit == Fruit.apple);
```

As covered in the referenced post, it is possible to achieve this functionality by extending the enum definition as follows:

```dart
enum Fruit {
  apple,
  orange,
  banana;

  static Fruit? fromName(String name) {
    for (var value in Fruit.values) {
      if (value.name == name) return value;
    }
    return null;
  }
}

// These now work as expected
final myFruit = Fruit.fromName('apple');
assert(myFruit == Fruit.apple);
assert(Fruit.fromName('orange') == Fruit.orange);
```

However this would need to be implemented in each enum where this functionality is required.

An alternative approach, as also [mentioned in the above post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77023200/9629046), is to use `Fruit.values.byName('orange')` or to modify that behaviour (eg because it throws if the value is not found) by creating a [custom extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77620101/9629046).

What I haven't been able to figure out is how to write a custom `extension on Enum` (or something similar) so that the simpler, more intuitive `Fruit.fromName('orange')` can be used with any plain enum definition such as `enum Fruit { apple, orange, banana }`.

I've tried various approaches by trying to modify the iterator based `extension` but have been unable to make it work. Borrowing heavily from the `EnumByName` [extension](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/EnumByName.html) I've tried variations on the following but they all come back to `.values` not being defined on `this` (or `Enum` or `T`)

```dart
extension EnumFromName on Enum {
  Enum? fromName(String name) {
    // this.values is not valid...
    for (var value in this.values) {
      if (value.name == name) return value;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Would appreciate any input or guidance on how to resolve and create this sort of extension.

Comment: It's not possible.  Your function either needs to be an extension on `Iterable<T extends Enum>` or it needs the `values` `List` passed as argument.  The Dart team wrote the `EnumByName` extension as it is for a reason.

Comment: This is something that code-gen must be involved in. [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) automatically converts strings into their corresponding enum value.